# Enable multiple HTTP Methods on a single operation?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I have an operation contract (below) that I want to allow GET and POST requests against.  How can I tell WCF to accept both types of requests for a single OperationContract?

```
[OperationContract,
WebInvoke(Method="POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    UriTemplate = "query")]
XElement Query(string qry);

[OperationContract,
WebInvoke(Method="GET",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    UriTemplate = "query?query={qry}")]
XElement Query(string qry);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This post over on the [MSDN Forums by Carlos Figueira](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/ad5bb2f0-058c-47ae-bcf3-8f5c4727a70e/) has a solution.  I'll go with this for now but if anyone else has any cleaner solutions let me know.

```
[OperationContract,
WebInvoke(Method="POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    UriTemplate = "query")]
XElement Query_Post(string qry);

[OperationContract,
WebInvoke(Method="GET",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    UriTemplate = "query?query={qry}")]
XElement Query_Get(string qry);
```

Answer (score 18):

Incase if anyone looking for a different solution,

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="*")]
public <> DoWork()
{
     var method = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Method;
     if (method == "POST") return DoPost();
     else if (method == "GET") return DoGet();
     throw new ArgumentException("Method is not supported.");
}
```

Comment: Method="*" is NOT recognized as valid. Allowed values are GET and POST.

Comment: It worked for me, too; but I could not find official documentation about that, nor here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.method(v=vs.110).aspx neither here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the WebGetAttribute, I have not tried it myself but you may be able to apply it to the same method along with the WebInvokeAttribute.

Info on [MSDN](http://jeffbarnes.net/portal/blogs/jeff_barnes/archive/2007/09/11/wcf-3-5-webget-attribute.aspx), and [Jeff Barnes](http://jeffbarnes.net/portal/blogs/jeff_barnes/archive/2007/09/11/wcf-3-5-webget-attribute.aspx).

Comment: There is no difference between WebInvoke(Method = "GET") and WebGet()

Answer (score 1):

For the issue described above, changing the WebInvoke to WebGet in the case of Query_Get API will solve the issue.

Comment: There is no difference between WebInvoke(Method = "GET") and WebGet()

Answer (score -1):

GET and POST imply different actions though.

Won't this be confusing for clients, and wrong from a REST perspective?

Comment: I'm coding the endpoint based on a specification from the W3C.  That specification describes one method that supports multiple operations (GET and POST).  If the query is to large for a GET request (URL length) the consumer can use POST.

Answer (score -3):

Not using WebInvoke will do the trick.

That may not be the answer you're looking for, though.