# Consume Service with GET and POST

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, web-services, wcf

I need to Consume WCF Service using GET AND POST ajaxcall. By using below code I can achieve POST method, now I want to consume wcf service using GET method. where do I need to change the code.

JS-

```
var para = { "ID": "87268" };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/Service/Review.svc/GetList',
                data: para,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) { }
})
```

WCF SERVICE-

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        string GetList(int ID);
```

WEB.CONFIG

```
<services>
  <service name="Service.Reviews" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service.IReviews" behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: have a look at this post. I believe it should give you an answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555073/enable-multiple-http-methods-on-a-single-operation

Comment: Be aware you can't send json to a web service via get, you can only send query string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Every place where you have "POST" you need to change to "GET", no?

Comment: I have tried that but still not getting correct response.